# Having trouble creating a regular expression

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio-2010, match

I want to check for a match in a string such that the string ends in a dash and then two digits. Therefore "bill-01" will be a match, as will "jared-43" but "josh" and "allen47-" won't. I just need a bool true/false to tell if a match was found for the given string.

Thank you.

Comment: "Having trouble" sounds like you have some existing code that you can't get to work, but I don't see any code. Are you sure you aren't just asking us to do it for you? Show your code.

Comment: No, you're exactly right. I'm trying to learn the regular expression language but each time I try to write a match case it fails. I could show you my attempts but that seems useless.

Comment: @user2340818, no, we _want you_ to show us your attempts, and explain why they did not work. That way we can help you fix them.

Comment: This, pattern: -\d{2}\z

Comment: @gunr2171, tnw, dont be jerks if someone is asking a very basic question, and is clearly trying to learn a new subject, you can be nice and helpful

Comment: @user2340818 \z matches the end of the string...

Comment: @AK_ I don't think they're being jerks at all. I respect their answers; the question really does seem like I'm asking for someone else to do my work for me.

Answer (score 1):

this will match anything as long as it ends with `-` followed by two numbers

```
.*-[0-9]{2}
```

http://txt2re.com/

http://www.regexr.com/

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_basic_and_extended

Have fun

Comment: Thank you, I will have a look there

Answer (score 0):

```
                    string pattern = @".*-\d{2}";
                    Match match = Regex.Match(arg, pattern);

                    Console.Write("{0} ", arg);

                    if (match.Success)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Matched");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("did NOT Match");
                    }
```